# Dell XPS 13 Not Discovering any Wifi Networks

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, drivers, debian, broadcom

So my wifi just died randomly this morning and I haven't been able to get it back would appreciate any help I can get.

I have been following this link with little to no success https://askubuntu.com/questions/841971/broadcom-bcm4352-wireless-not-working-with-16-10 here are my results of running the same types of tests

lshw -C network

```
*-network                 
   description: Wireless interface
   product: BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter
   vendor: Broadcom Limited
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
   logical name: wlan0
   version: 03
   serial: 6a:cc:51:5a:8b:d9
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=wl0 driverversion=6.30.223.271 (r587334) latency=0 multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
   resources: irq:19 memory:f7200000-f7207fff memory:f7000000-f71fffff
```

rfkill list all

```
 0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

lspci -knn | grep -A2 Net

```
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Limited BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [14e4:43b1] (rev 03)
Subsystem: Dell BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter [1028:0019]
Kernel driver in use: wl
Kernel modules: bcma, wl
```

I have also refollowed the installation guide for wl but haven't had any success yet would appreciate any help I can get.

Comment: Let's start with the simple, common things.  Did you try the key toggle?  Probably Fn+PrtScr on that model.

Comment: @Jason Thank you I am very foolish that was it I now remember doing that but did not notice the correlation I was trying to take a screenshot... Not my brightest day appreciate the help!

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem was caused by user error; the answer is unlikely to be of great help to other users (and the question is unlikely to attract any better answers).

Comment: @WillWhitlow You're welcome.  It's gotten me before, so I can sympathize.  People here seem to prefer obscure answers rather than practical ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Toggle Wi-Fi on using <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>PrtScr</kbd>.